# how to work with vtiger library java?

Tags: java, android, vtiger

VTiger lib for java is not working properly, I used the documentation for `vtwsclib.jar`, and implemented the examples given in documentation but I always get `false`.

Is there an alternative way to use vtiger for android? 
I also used libray developed by @Vitaly,  https://github.com/vitalidze/vtiger-client, but it gave this error:

```
## Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder

>>at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:103)
at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
at su.litvak.vtiger.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:113)
at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:206)
at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
... 2 more
```

Comment: What documentation have you used? What does exactly means that you always get `false`?

Answer (score 1):

The screen shot show that you are missing libraries, include all the libraries. Actually i used these libraries too but could not achieved my goal. so i used my own web-services to work with Vtiger. i had a question and got an answer mine and yours are not related but in answer he gave me some links which are all docs of vtiger so i will suggest you to study them first while creating your own webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is missing a library.

Make sure you import the library to your project.
under project explorer "your project name"-> Libraries, rightclick on library and  click ADD JAR/FOLDER
find "vtwsclib.jar" and import it.
it should fix the problem.